# node's FQDN is missing in chef

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

am a newbie to the chef and knife, I am running couple of ec2 instances and have install chef-client and I can see all the instances in the node list of the chef, but couple of them are missing FQDN which is causing hell lot of problem, here is the output when I run knife node show node_name

```
Environment: _default
FQDN:        
IP:          
Run List:    
Roles:       
Recipes:     
Platform:     
Tags:
```

You can see expect Env rest all other are blank. How do I fix this problem. Kindly help me out

Comment: AFAIK chef-client should finish successfully at least once on the node, before it stores all the automatic (provided by ohai) attributes on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These attributes aren't set until after the first successful Chef Client run. If the Chef Client run is not completing successfully, this information is not stored on the server.